# Что значит аннотация @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate?

Tags: java, jvm, аннотации

Смотрел JVM, наткнулся на аннотацию `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate`, довольно часто ее стал встречать. Что она значит? Раньше ее не было.

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/tip/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate.java

Comment: @Ivan, спасибо, уже нашел.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Начал искать дальше, вот что нашел в комментариях к аннотации(оказывается, и такие есть).

> The `{@code @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate}` annotation is specific to the
>   *HotSpot Virtual Machine.* It indicates that an annotated method may be (but is not guaranteed to be) intrinsified by the *HotSpot VM*. A
>   method is intrinsified if the *HotSpot VM* replaces the annotated
>   method with hand-written assembly and/or hand-written compiler IR -- a
>   compiler intrinsic -- to improve performance. The
>   `{@code @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate}` annotation is internal to the Java
>   libraries and is therefore not supposed to have any relevance for
>   application code.
>
> Persons not directly involved with maintaining the Java libraries or
>   the *HotSpot VM* can safely ignore the fact that a method is annotated
>   with `{@code @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate}`.

Примерный перевод:

> Аннотация `{@code @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate}` предназначена для
>   *HotSpot Virtual Machine*. Это означает, что аннотированный метод может быть (но не гарантированно), встроен в *HotSpot VM*.
>   Метод встроен, если *HotSpot VM* заменяет аннотированный
>   рукописной сборкой и/или рукописным компилятором IR -
>   встроенным компилятором - для повышения производительности.
>   `{@Code @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate}`аннотация является внутренней для Java
>   библиотеки и поэтому не должна иметь никакого отношения к
>   коду приложения.
>
> Лица, не имеющие непосредственного отношения к поддержке библиотек Java или
>   *HotSpot VM* могут смело игнорировать тот факт, что метод аннотирован
>    `{@code @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate}`.